# postgres: Any way to insert multiple tables into another table in the same query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have a bunch of tables and I want to insert them all into another table where all entries from the table and with a label of the name of the title of their table.

Here is a sample of what I want to be doing but with also logging in old users at the same time from an oldusers table

```
insert into growth_accounting_weekly (userid, week_ending, status)
    select 
        permid, 
        (select current_date - extract(dow from current_date)::integer), 
        'New' 
    from newusers,
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNION will to the trick. Or UNION ALL, like this:

```
insert into growth_accounting_weekly (userid, week_ending, status)
select 
    permid, 
    (select current_date - extract(dow from current_date)::integer), 
    'New' 
from newusers
UNION ALL
select another_id, another_number, another_status
FROM another table
```

Note that fields must have the same type.

Thake a look to: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-union/

Comment: Glad to help. If ok, please, accept solution.